# HeadlessUI Dialog component renders instantly regardless of whether it is in a transition element

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, headless-ui

I'm trying to open a dialog with a transition in Nuxt.js, but it always renders instantly.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <TransitionRoot
      :show="isOpen"
      enter="transition-opacity duration-300"
      enter-from="opacity-0"
      enter-to="opacity-100"
      leave="transition-opacity duration-300"
      leave-from="opacity-100"
      leave-to="opacity-0"
      as="template"
    >
      <div>
        Text outside of Dialog
        <Dialog as="div" class="relative z-10">Text inside of dialog</Dialog>
      </div>
    </TransitionRoot>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { TransitionRoot, Dialog, DialogPanel, DialogTitle, TransitionChild, DialogDescription } from '@headlessui/vue'

defineProps({
  isOpen: Boolean,
})
</script>
```

The text outside of the Dialog will use the transition, but the text inside of it pops up immediately. This structure is also used on the HeadlessUI website, but there the content does actually fade in. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating headless ui to 1.6.6

They fixed some dialog issues recently

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/pull/1653